# Ask if this number is odd or even , as many times you want

Tags: python, function, loops, numbers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tkgC.png)

i want to use function in simple prigram
but it`s giving me wrong result in a wrong way

i wanna make a loop with function and ask as many time i want to see if the number i enterd is odd or even

```
def new_game():
game()


def game():
    a = int(input("please enter the number... "))
    if a % 2 == 0:
        print(a, " Is even ")
    else:
        print(a, " Is odd ")


game()


def check():
    ask = input("Do you want to continue ? yes/no  ").lower()
    if ask == 'yes':
       return True
    elif ask == 'no':
        exit()
    else:
        print('Bye')


while check():
    game()
    check()
    break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually had it. But the break in your while loop is not needed and is what is causing your problem. Say you entered `y`, it will exit `check()` and break. Remove that.

```
while check():
    game()
    check()
    #break is gone
```

full code

```
def game():
    a = int(input("please enter the number... "))
    if a % 2 == 0:
        print(a, " Is even ")
    else:
        print(a, " Is odd ")




def check():
    ask = input("Do you want to continue ? yes/no  ").lower()
    if ask == 'yes':
       return True
    elif ask == 'no':
        exit()
    else:
        print('Bye')

game()
while check():
    game()
    check()
```

Comment: wouldn't this be calling check() twice in every iteration?

Comment: no it will. You play the game, then check. Play the game then check.

Comment: Hmm, i thought it would play>check>play>check>check>play>check>check>play etc...